# kubernetes create cluster with logging and monitoring for ubuntu

Tags: kubernetes

I'm setting up a kubernetes cluster on digitalocean ubuntu machines. I got the cluster up and running following this [get started guide ubuntu](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu.md). During the setup the **ENABLE_NODE_LOGGING**, **ENABLE_CLUSTER_LOGGING** and **ENABLE_CLUSTER_DNS** variables are set to true in the **config-default.sh**.

However there is no controller, services created for elasticsearch/kabana. I did have to run the deployAddon.sh manually for the skydns, do I need to do the same for logging and monitoring ? or am I missing something in the default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

By default the logging and monitoring services are not in the default namespace.

You should be able to see if the services are running with `kubectl cluster-info`.

To look at the individual services/controllers, specify the kube-system namespace:

`kubectl get service --namespace=kube-system`

Comment: The solution does not address the question appropriately

Answer (score 0):

By default, logging and monitor is not enabled if you are installing kubernetes on ubuntu machines. It looks like someone has copied the config-default.sh script from some other folder, hence the variables ENABLE_NODE_LOGGING and ENABLE_CLUSTER_LOGGING are copied but are not used to bring up the relevant logging deployments and services.

As @Jon Mumm said, `kubectl cluster-info` gives you the info. But if you want to install the logging service, go to

```
kubernetes/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch
```

and run

```
kubectl create -f es-controller.yaml -f es-service.yaml -f kibana-controller.yaml -f kibana-service.yaml
```

with right setup. Change the yaml files to suit your configuration and ensure kubectl is in your path.

Update 1: This will bring up kibana and logstash services